# Making square footprint polygons in QGIS

Tags: qgis, footprint

We are a group of students working with footprint taken from LiDAR point cloud. We have a challenge in making the polygons more square. We want the angles to be orthogonal, and the sides to be longer than eg 3 meters. We have tried QGIS "generalized" and "simplified", but are not completely satisfied.
Does anyone know of a good tool for this task?

[image]

Comment: Given your minimum size requirement, I doubt an off-the-shelf tool exists, but calculating a custom minimum bounding rectangle (MBR) in PyQGIS shouldn't be all that difficult.

Comment: It could work to for each building create a fishnet of small squares, oriented by a minimum bounding geometry, then select by location on the small squares, and dissolve. Wont be perfect though

Comment: You may get an acceptable result by combining "Orthogonalize" and "Simplify" tools sequentially (multiple times) depending on your data.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Since it is involving several thousand building footprint, I choose to use the proposed method with simplified and orthogonalize tools in Qgis. Thank you for your input